# Find out the nth-highest salary from table

Tags: sql, oracle11g, greatest-n-per-group

```
name   salary
-----   -----
mohan     500
ram      1000
dinesh   5000
hareesh  6000
mallu    7500
manju    7500
praveen 10000
hari    10000
```

How would I find the nth-highest salary from the aforementioned table using Oracle?

Comment: Use RANK or DENSE_RANK, what is more appropriate for your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use something like this.. this is what i have tested and then pasted here

```
SELECT *
FROM   tblname
WHERE  salary = (SELECT *
                 FROM   (SELECT *
                         FROM   (SELECT *
                                 FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT( salary )
                                         FROM   tblname
                                         ORDER  BY salary DESC) A
                                 WHERE  rownum <= nth) B
                         ORDER  BY salary ASC) C
                 WHERE  rownum <= 1)
```

in place of **'tblname'** give your table name and then in place **nth** give your desired nth highest salary that you want

[image]

you can see in the screen shot that it is working.

Comment: you can see that this solution is for oracle. for sql it will be very different...

Comment: sorry but see this... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ef767/18 this is exactly the same i posted in the answer... it is working fine..

Comment: also in your link ... the third highest is the 10000 and not the 5000 as there is a hari2 with 20000 and then there is hari1 with 13000... please see for your self..

Comment: +1 I got it Gaurav. Your solution was correct. The mistake was misinterpretation of Order By to take.

Comment: Now I can't upvote since I already voted to ur post 18 hrs before. Sorry for that

Comment: no worries... i just wish other people who find this answer correct and helpful.. do upvote it...

Answer (score 4):

```
select * 
  from ( select s.*, rank() over (order by salary desc) as rownumber
           from salary )
 where rownumber = nth
```

pass your salary number in place of "nth"

Comment: select * from (
    select rank() over(order by salary DESC) as rownumber,* from  second_salary) SalaryRank 
    where rownumber = 3

Comment: i try above mentioned query

Comment: what is the datatype of your salary colomn

Comment: It should work. Try with other numeric data type like int float decimal.. . missing expression means some where you are missing comma or bracket.

Comment: You were missing a dot @kuldeep... you should probably also use ROW_NUMBER() instead as well a rank() will provide the same value in the event of a tie.

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from 
(
    select sal, rank() over (order by sal DESC/ASC) rnk 
    from emp
) 
where rnk = 1/2/3/4/5/6/...;
```

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/find-nth-highest-salary-sql/) talks about this question in depth, and I will quote code from it below: (Note: see  the bottom 2 solutions for Oracle)

**Solution 1:** This SQL to find the Nth highest salary should work in SQL Server, MySQL, DB2, Oracle, Teradata, and almost any other RDBMS: (note: low performance because of subquery)

```
SELECT * /*This is the outer query part */
FROM Employee Emp1
WHERE (N-1) = ( /* Subquery starts here */
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Emp2.Salary))
FROM Employee Emp2
WHERE Emp2.Salary > Emp1.Salary)
```

The most important thing to understand in the query above is that the subquery is evaluated each and every time a row is processed by the outer query. In other words, the inner query can not be processed independently of the outer query since the inner query uses the Emp1 value as well.

In order to find the Nth highest salary, we just find the salary that has exactly N-1 salaries greater than itself.

---

**Solution 2:** Find the nth highest salary using the TOP keyword in SQL Server

```
SELECT TOP 1 Salary
FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT TOP N Salary
      FROM Employee
      ORDER BY Salary DESC
      ) AS Emp
ORDER BY Salary
```

---

**Solution 3:** Find the nth highest salary in SQL Server without using TOP

```
SELECT Salary FROM Employee 
ORDER BY Salary DESC OFFSET N-1 ROW(S) 
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

Note that I haven’t personally tested the SQL above, and I believe that it will only work in SQL Server 2012 and up.

---

**Solution 4:** Works in MySQL

```
SELECT Salary FROM Employee 
ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT n-1,1
```

The LIMIT clause takes two arguments in that query – the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return.

---

**Solution 5:** Works in Oracle

```
select * from (
  select Emp.*, 
row_number() over (order by Salary DESC) rownumb 
from Employee Emp
)
where rownumb = n;  /*n is nth highest salary*/
```

---

**Solution 6:** Works in Oracle way 2

```
select * FROM (
select EmployeeID, Salary
,rank() over (order by Salary DESC) ranking
from Employee
)
WHERE ranking = N;
```

Answer (score 1):

**General query** for all Database

```
SELECT DISTINCT salary FROM emp X WHERE n = 
    ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT salary) FROM emp WHERE salary >=X.salary )
```

Replace n with the given number. 
for example to get the 3rd highest salary

```
SELECT DISTINCT salary FROM emp X WHERE 3 = 
( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT salary) FROM emp WHERE salary >=X.salary )
```

OR

**in any programming language**

select * from emp order by salary

then iterate the result set in programming language (JAVA, .net or php)

### Mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT salary FROM emp X order by salary desc limit n,1
```

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged your question Oracle so you could just use the [`NTH_VALUE()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions114.htm#SQLRF30031) function... it's an analytic function unfortunately but your query would be simplified to:

```
select distinct nth_value(salary, 3) over ()
  from employees
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/27a0d/4)

From 12c Oracle finally catches up with the rest of the world and includes OFFSET so you could use this instead:

```
select salary
  from employees
 order by salary
offset n - 1
 fetch next row only
```

Comment: select sal, ename, nth_value(sal, 3) over()
 from scott.emp

Is not giving correct result unless it is ordered

select sal, ename, nth_value(sal, 3) over()
 from scott.emp
order by sal

Comment: select sal, ename, nth_value(sal, 3) over()
 from scott.emp

This is also working

Answer (score 1):

DECLARE M INT;
SET M=N-1;
SELECT DISTINCT Salary FROM Employee
ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT M,1;

Answer (score 0):

You can find plenty of stuff on google

```
select * 
  from table_name T1 
 where Nth = (select count(distinct (T2.sal)) 
                from table_name T2 
               where T1.sal <= T2.sal )
```

Comment: I missed the last ")". try it now.

Answer (score 0):

Select n-th highest salary in a simple way

```
SELECT emp_no, sal
FROM
(
select emp_no, sal, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by sal desc) RN 
from emp 
order by sal desc
)
WHERE RN = n;
```

Where n = the n-th number u want.....

Answer (score 0):

Refer following query for getting nth highest salary. By this way you get nth highest salary. If you want get nth lowest salary only you need to replace DESC by ASC in the query. 
[image: for getting nth highest salry]

Comment: Mentioned 2 times on this thread with instructions to mysql. Unfortunately, Oracle does not have an operator like LIMIT.

Answer (score 0):

In MySql, run the below SQL to find nth highest salary:

```
SELECT distinct(salary), emp_id, name 
       FROM `emp_salary` 
       group by salary 
       order by salary desc limit N-1,1;
```

e.g Find 3rd highest salary:

```
SELECT distinct(salary), emp_id, name 
       FROM `emp_salary` 
       group by salary 
       order by salary desc limit 2,1;
```

e.g Find 3rd lowest salary (make "order by asc"):

```
SELECT distinct(salary), emp_id, name 
       FROM `emp_salary` 
       group by salary 
       order by salary asc limit 2,1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Sql server 2012 and above. Please Refer this link for [Fetch, Offset, Sql server Page](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2362/overview-of-offset-and-fetch-feature-of-sql-server-2012/)

```
 Use AdventureWorks /* AdventureWorks 2014 DB*/

Select distinct(CommissionPct) from Sales.SalesPerson
order by CommissionPct desc OffSet 3 Rows Fetch next 1 Rows only

--This for 4Th highest value (N-1)
```

[Look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MOme.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try out following in Oracle:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT rownum AS rn,
    a.*
  FROM
    (WITH DATA AS -- creating dummy data
    ( SELECT 'MOHAN' AS NAME, 200 AS SALARY FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'AKSHAY' AS NAME, 500 AS SALARY FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'HARI' AS NAME, 300 AS SALARY FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'RAM' AS NAME, 400 AS SALARY FROM DUAL
    )
  SELECT D.* FROM DATA D ORDER BY SALARY DESC
    ) A
  )
WHERE rn = 3; -- specify N'th highest here (In this case fetching 3'rd highest)
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by correlated subquery.

```
SELECT Salary
FROM Employee E1
WHERE N-1 = (SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM Employee E2
         WHERE E1.salary <E2.Salary)
```

For further knowledge please check this link..
[Correlated Subquery with example](http://dotnetauthorities.blogspot.in/2013/12/Microsoft-SQL-Server-Training-Online-Learning-Classes-Sql-Sub-Queries-Nested-Co-related.html)

Answer (score 0):

select distinct salary from emp_table order by salary desc limit n-1,1;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT SALARY, DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY SALARY DESC) nth_salary FROM EMPLOYEES)WHERE nth_salary = 1;
```

It pretty much works in Oracle. You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` function instead `DENSE_RANK` but it selects only one record or row for the highest salary even if there are two or more employees having the equal salary.