# Oracle Sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

There is an employee table having salary column.
How to find the second highest salary among a list of employees?? 
Is there any convenient way to find the any nth number of salary ??

Comment: Please post the DDL statements for your tables, example input, expected output plus the queries you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has a rank function. Based on the result of this function you can select the nth number.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions123.htm

See also this question and answer:
[Nth max salary in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091125/nth-max-salary-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

Second Highest Salary

```
SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee
WHERE Salary NOT IN (SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee )
```

Nth Highest Salary

```
SELECT * 
FROM Employee Emp1
WHERE (N-1) = ( 
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Emp2.Salary))
FROM Employee Emp2
WHERE Emp2.Salary > Emp1.Salary)
```

Comment: Pretty inefficient for large data sets

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 12c you have function 'NTH_VALUE' you can use for this.