# What is the efficient query to find out Nth highest salary

Tags: sql, oracle

I am just a beginner..
I know `SQL` queries to find out 3rd highest salary or nth highest salary. But I need an **efficient** query.

These are the queries that I know.. Could you please suggest any other queries instead of these..

This query is not efficient as per my subject teacher

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee Emp1
WHERE (N-1) = (
               SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Emp2.Salary))
               FROM Employee Emp2
               WHERE Emp2.Salary > Emp1.Salary
               );
```

And this query obviously is not efficient

```
SELECT MAX(Salary) 
FROM Employee
WHERE Salary NOT IN (SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee );
```

Any hint?

Comment: Is this for MySQL or Oracle database?

Comment: Assuming there are `1 1 1 1 1 2 3` entries. Which one will be 3rd?

Comment: Why have you tagged both MySQL and Oracle? `DENSE_RANK` or `ROW_NUMBER` will likely be the most efficient way but MySQL doesn't support this.

Comment: @zerkms with all records 1 1 1 1 1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find out the nth-highest salary from table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285903/find-out-the-nth-highest-salary-from-table)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Employee
ORDER BY
    Salary DESC
LIMIT N,1
```

And from performance pov it would really help if you had an index on `Salary` column

**UPDATE:** 
since the `mysql` tag is gone you could use the oracle alternative also mentioned by *mhasan* [ROWNUM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**ROW_NUMBER()**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) analytic function for ranking according to salary.
Assumming you want 5th highest salary

```
Select * From

(

Select col1,col2,
       row_number() over( order by salary desc) as rnkSalary
From employees
)z

Where  z.rnkSalary=5
```